# Limit of a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, periodic-functions

I stumbled upon this question in my course, and I am out of ideas. Let $f$ be a periodic function $$f(x)=f(x+l), \qquad l>0$$

**Prove** that if it is not constant, then $\lim_{x\to 0}f\left(\frac1x\right)$ does not exist.

I don't understand why it's true, let alone how to prove it.

Comment: Can you prove that _if_ the limit exists, then the function must be constant (and equal to the limit)?

Comment: Intuition: Try to picture the map $x\mapsto x^-1$ Where happens to infinity under this map? what happens to small neighbourhoods of 0? Can you see what happens to the function when the argument maps this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} f(1/x) = a$ exists. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Now there exist $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align}
|x| < \delta & \implies |f(1/x) - a| < \varepsilon\,.
\end{align}
This is equivalent with
$$
|y| > 1/\delta \implies |f(y) - a | < \varepsilon\,.
$$
Thus for all $y \in (1/\delta, \infty)$ we have $f(y) \in (a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$.

Because $f(y-l) = f(y)$ this implies that for all $y \in (1/\delta -l, \infty)$ we have $f(y) \in (a- \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$. Continuing this shows that $f(y) \in (a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we must have $f(y) = a$ for all $y$.

So if the limit exists, $f$ is constant. Thus if $f$ is not constant, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\exists a, b :$ $f(a) \ne f(b)$.

Let $\exists \lim_{x \to 0} f(\frac{1}{x}) = c$.

Let $\epsilon > 0: |f(\frac{1}{x}) - c| < \frac{|f(a) - f(b)|}{2}\  \forall x \in (0, \epsilon).$

But $\frac{1}{a + nl}, \frac{1}{b + nl} \to 0$ if $n \to \infty$.

Then $\exists n:  \frac{1}{a + nl}, \frac{1}{b + nl} \in (0, \epsilon).$

Then $$|f(a) - f(b)| = |f(a + nl) - f(b + nl)| =|f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a + nl}}) - f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b + nl}})| \le $$$$|f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a + nl}}) - c| + |f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b + nl}}) - c| < \frac{|f(a) - f(b)|}{2} + \frac{|f(a) - f(b)|}{2} = |f(a) - f(b)|.  $$